# Need help with json/jquery

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp, href

Ok so I'm pulling in a jsonp feed with jquery and then trying to format my widget to work with the data.

I have it 90% working but I can't figure out the how to get a `<a href="">` to have the value of my link that is "item.url" in my jsonp.

I know I'm missing some code for the `"var url= $('<div>').attr("href",item.url);"` part but I cn't for the life of me figure out how to get it to work! :(

Here is my code:

```
gv_responce = function (response) {
    // we destroy the script element.
    scriptElement.parentNode.removeChild(scriptElement);

    //we have all the information in response variable in a json format,
    //we just format the results.
    for (keyItem in response.posts) {
        var item = response.posts[keyItem];
        var img = $('<img>').attr('src', item.thumbnail);
        var div = $('<div>').append(img);
        var title = $('<div>').html($.trim(item.title));
        var text = $('<div>').html($.trim(item.excerpt));
        var url = $('<div>').attr("href", item.url);

        div.append(title);
        div.append(text);
        div.attr('class', 'gv');
        $('#content').append(item.from_user);
        $('#content').append(div);
    }

}
})();
```

//when everything is loaded we call the api ...

```
jQuery(document).ready(LKS.makeRequest());
```

Comment: According to your code, you're creating a bunch of DIVs and populating them with some HTML and setting an 'href' attribute on it. Is that what you actually want to do?

Comment: div not have attribute of href , http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DIV.asp

Comment: @Haim, I think it's valid in HTML5 now

Comment: @JohnP - Doesn't mean the browser would actually navigation based on the DIV's href attribute.  That is, if that is the actual use-case for the OP's implementation.

Comment: @Gregg I haven't actually tried it out. Block level links are allowed but not 100% sure about the whether href is usable or not though

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
var url = $('<div>').attr("href", item.url);
```

be

```
var url = $('<a>').attr("href", item.url);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace the line

```
var url = $('<div>').attr("href", item.url);
```

with

```
var url = $('<a>').attr("href", item.url);
```

afterwards, you'll want to add the  to your DOM

```
$('#content').append(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write something in 'a' tag's html. You have also created 'a' tag but you just couldn't see.

try this;

```
var url= $('<a>').attr("href",item.url).html('itemName');
```

instead of

```
var url= $('<a>').attr("href",item.url);
```